# How to translate a C struct to managed C# equivalent

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, interop, unmanaged

I have the following struct (example) in C:

```
typedef struct 
{
     int64      data_size;
     uint32      avgdelay;   
     int         esize;      
     void       *epayload;  
} stats_t;
```

The managed C# equivalent is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 4)]
public struct stats_t
{
    public Int64 datasize;

    public UInt32 avgdelay;

    public Int32 esize;

    public IntPtr epayload;

}
```

When a parameter of type stats_t is used in an invoked callback delegate I found it necessary to include a dummy UInt32 member to be able to invoke the callback via the delegate in order to preserve the byte pattern of the callback signature

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 4)]
public struct stats_t
{
    public Int64 datasize;

    public UInt32 avgdelay;

    public Int32 esize;

    public IntPtr epayload;

    /// dummy member for alignment
    public UInt32 dummy;

}
```

The callback signature is the following:

```
  int Callback_Proc( stats_t stats, void *user, int final, int error, int code);
```

The delegate for the callback has the following signature:

```
  public delegate int Callback_Proc(stats_t stats, IntPtr user, Int32 final, Int32 error, Int32 code);
```

I am wondering why the dummy member is needed in order to get the callback to work. Without the dummy the value of *final* was shifted to *error*, and value of *error* was shifted to *code*.
Thanks for your understanding and hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Are you compiling and running both the C++ and C# process on the same bit size OS and compilation? At first glance, I might assume that the C++ process is 64-bit and the C# 32-bit, so IntPtr would be 4 bytes vs. 8 bytes for the C++ void*.

Comment: Perhaps you are on a 64-bit system that requires 64-bit quanta for structs?  Is there any reason  you don't just use a class in C#?

Comment: Both C++ and C# use the same x86 bitness. Also there is a separate build for x64 for C++ and C# code.

Comment: `Size = 4` is too nonsensical to be believable, the struct is much larger than that.  My crystal ball says that you actually wrote `Pack = 4`.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the size of the IntPtr. I assume your C++ code is compiled for 64 bits, so the void* pointer size expected by the C++ code is 8 bytes, but .net has a very ugly preference for 32 bits, if you compile for AnyCPU, the project still has an (stupid) flag named "Prefer 32 bits" on the compile options, so even if the code is executed on a 64 bit machine it will run at 32 bits causing pointers to be 4 bytes long.

Remove the "prefer 32 bits" from the project or compile explicitly to x64, that should correct your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have two build configurations x86 and x64 respectively. I got rid of the AnyCPU configuration a while ago.

Comment: then may be the problem is at esize, does your c++ compiler treat "int" as "int32" or "int64"? I say "may be" because that sould make the payload pointer to be displaced and fail it's read...

Comment: Thanks, I believe this could be the answer because before the dummy implementation I had the callback working with esize as Int64